# How to turn this hover dependant css code into a click on/off function

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<h1 id="Title">Hover Me</h1>-
```

CSS

```
h1::before {  
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

h1:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

h1::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: hsl(200 100% 80%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

Im trying to turn this into an effect that turns on/off by clicking the tittle.

I  have tried changing it into a class and then making the hover a different one and try to toggle between these two classes

```
document.getElementById("Title").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("Title");
  element.classList.toggle("Transform");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `:hover` pseudo-class with `.Transform` to match the element when it has the `"Transform"` class. Then, toggling the class on click will work.

```js
document.getElementById("Title").addEventListener("click", 
  e => e.target.classList.toggle("Transform"));
```

```css
h1::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
h1.Transform::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
h1::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: hsl(200 100% 80%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Title">Click Me</h1>-
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Unmitigated has given you a good solution. But I understanded your question in a different way. so here is my answer based on @Unmitigated code.
change `h1.Transform::before` to `h1.Transform:hover::before`